# Displaying images in a java web project

Tags: java, image, web

So, i'm trying to do something simple: Display an image in my java web app.

I built a simple app for that, but i'm not succeeding, I tried all different things I could find, but no success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>test page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>testing internal libraries</h1>
    <img src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/WebContent/images/cp.jpg" width=30 />
    <img src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/images/cp.jpg" width=30 />
    <img src="../images/cp.jpg" width=30 />
    <img src="images/cp.jpg" width=30 />
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

[image]

***EDIT:***

That's the source code shown by google chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>test page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>testing internal libraries</h1>
<img src="/teste/WebContent/images/cp.jpg" width=30 />
<img src="/teste/images/cp.jpg" width=30 />
<img src="../images/cp.jpg" width=30 />
<img src="images/cp.jpg" width=30 />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you deploying war file? If yes have you checked that images are actually included into that war?

Comment: @Ivan I'm not sure how to check that, i'm running the web app in eclipse using tomcat though, how should I check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i'd like to point that while what fixed my problem was something else, the answers and comments here can help people finding other problems causing the same issue, I believe.

So the solution was rather simple:

> I had my "index" mapped in a wrong way in the `web.xml`, which was causing the context path to get all weird

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.MainServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**The fix was removing the `/` from the url pattern**, for some reason I always thought you'd need that for the "index page" and in some other languages (node for example) I usually map my index with "/", but it doesn't seem to be the case for java.

So my code turned out like this in the `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.MainServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And the mapping in the image was basically:

```
<img src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/WebContent/images/cp.jpg" width=30 />
```

Like already mentioned by @Molina Henrique

Answer (score 1):

The correct is `<img src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/images/cp.jpg" width=30 />`

But before, Let's configure your Path at Eclipse IDE:

select your project > Click button right > Build Path > Configure Build Path... >
Tab **Source**

Check in the field "*Default output folder*" if there is *teste/target/classes*
**change to** teste/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes

recompile and try again!

Comment: hey, I did all that you told me to do, but still no success, It indeed created a new "classes" folder inside the "WEB-INF" with the .class but the image is still not showing. Anything else I could provide to help identifying the problem?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira `WEB-INF` isn't visible outside, it's where you put things you don't want to be seen (hence `/classes` is there). One directory up (here named WebConfig) is where the visible pictures are. Open up the war (it's a zip file) and look where the images are (if they are in there).

Comment: @Kayaman Sorry for my ignorance, but in order to look up the war, do I have to export the Project to ".WAR" or it is already deployed in my system somewhere?

Comment: The image did come within the "images" folder when I opened the .WAR file

Comment: How you are build your .war ? 
Pease check your  "Project Facets" at Properties in your project teste , every thing is ok ?

Comment: @MolinaHenrique I clicked export ".WAR". In Project facets the "Dynamic Web Module", "Java", "Javascript" checkboxes are checked, the other ones are not